# I can't seem to be able to asynchonously add a row onto a table of the @angular/material:table schematic

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, asynchronous, angular-material

When using the `@angular/material:table` schematic, I can't seem to be able to asynchonously add rows. Invoking `this.table.renderRows()` doesn't change that behavior. While the "works" part visibly is added onto the table (and increases the amount of rows on the paginator), the asynchronously added "doesn't work" only shows up as an increased number on the paginator row count instead of also being added as a new row.

I can't be the only one wanting to achieve this exact thing, so it's probably about me taking the wrong approach. What's the correct way of doing it?

Reproduction:

1. Initialize Project `ng new stackoverflow1; cd stackoverflow1`
2. Add angular material `ng add @angular/material`
3. Add schematic `ng generate @angular/material:table table`
4. Put `<app-table></app-table>` into `src/app/app.component.html`
5. Put

```js
setTimeout(() => {
    this.dataSource.data.push({id: 0, name: 'doesn\'t work'})
}, 1)
this.dataSource.data.push({id: 1, name: 'works'})
```

at the end of the ngAfterViewInit function of `src/app/table/table.component.ts` 
6. Serve the app `ng serve -o`

```
OS: Ubuntu 20.04 on WSL2 Windows 10 version 2004
Browser: Firefox 82.0.2, Chrome 86.0.4240.183
Angular CLI: 10.2.0
Node: 10.19.0
```

Comment: replicating the issue in a stackblitz and providing a link may be helpful, vs asking the community to stand up an environment to replicate the issue.

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose, it is needed to use a MatTableDataSource. We can completely dunk the provided TableDataSource (and the TableItem) for a new MatTableDataSource.

At the beginning of "table.component.ts":

```
import {MatTableDataSource} from '@angular/material/table';
```

Before @Component:

```
interface TableItem {
  name,
  address,
  ...
}
```

After the second @ViewChild:

```
@ViewChild(MatTable) table: MatTable<TableItem>;
dataSource: MatTableDataSource<TableItem>;
```

In ngOnInit():

```
this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<TableItem>();
```

After doing so, the following code should go through smoothly and your table should be update immediately after pushing the data:

```
setTimeout(()=>{
  this.dataSource.data.push(({id: 0, name: 'works again!'});
},1)
```

Comment: If I write it like that, it gives me an error: "Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'TableDataSource'."

Comment: With a few changes, that worked. I'd like to suggest an edit though, to make clearer what I did, as it wasn't completely what you suggested. Thank you for your help!